# Does the standard library for C++ exist on Game Consoles

Tags: c++, std, game-development

Kind of an unneeded question but I still wonder, do game consoles like the Xbox, Playstation, Nintendo Switch, ect. Have an implemmentation of the std C++ library or do they using something else, I looked for some information on this, but I couldn't find anything. Thanks!

Comment: The question should be "How much of the standard library do they contain?"  Game consoles fall more into the embedded systems category than the desktop.  Thus they have less memory and less resources.  The consoles will use only what they need from the std C++ library.

Answer (score 1):

C++ development systems for the consoles you mention do include the standard library.

And of course "something else" can also be used, just like anywhere else.